# import pandas using IDLE error

Tags: python, pandas, module

This is a beginner question. I am using "import pandas as pd" in IDLE,
but got the following error message "ImportError: No module named 'pandas", 
I don't know how to install the the pandas in IDLE. I run the same code in MAC linux command window, it worked. Not sure why not working in IDLE.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using different Python versions in IDLE and the command line, if this is the case, you should install Pandas for the Python version that you are using in IDLE